# Restoring a raw PostgreSQL backup from an ancient server?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

All the guides I can find suggest that migrating a psql database is really easy. Just call `pg_dump` out at one end and then you can just suck it up at the other. Really simple ***if* you remembered to `pg_dump`!**

Two years or so ago, I migrated a server from a crusty old 32bit server to a much newer, fresher 64bit install. I backed up the essentials (/etc, /var, /home, etc...) but being quite new to it at the time, I completely ignored PostgreSQL and didn't restore it on the new server.

Sound odd? Well the client only uses it for a Moodle site they only use once in a moon and has never needed it in all this time. Well it's full moon today. Client is savage that their database isn't available.

I have all the `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/...` files from the initial backup still. I could try to supplant the new `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/...` files but this is also a different arch, and I've read several things suggesting that won't work. I don't want things to get any worse.

Is there a good way to restore this old database or somehow convert it into neutral plaintext SQL that can be reimported?

Comment: You could start by running a postgres-9.1 instance on the new machine, possibly at a different portnumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that 64-bit PostgreSQL can't read a 32-bit PostgreSQL data directory. Nor could 9.3 read a 9.1 data directory.

You will need 32-bit PostgreSQL 9.1 to access this.

Because your x86_64 CPU can run 32-bit binaries without emulation, you have a couple of options:

- Install 32-bit PostgreSQL 9.1 using Debian/Ubuntu packages directly on your current system, pulling in any required 32-bit libraries. I'd probably try this first, as it might be easiest. Check http://apt.postgresql.org/ to see if there are 32-bit 9.1 binaries for your OS.
- Failing that, launch a virtual machine running the original operating system the data directory was created on using libvirt+kvm, Vagrant+virtualbox, or whatever, then install PostgreSQL 9.1 from the original OS packages on it.
- As a final alternative you could install a 32-bit gcc and the relevant PostgreSQL dependencies (`apt-get build-essential:i386`, `apt-get build-dep postgresql:i386` I think, but I don't have a Debian/Ubuntu machine to hand to test with) then compile PostgreSQL 9.1 for i386 using that toolchain.

Whichever way you do it, you will want to use the 9.1 binaries to to `PATH=/path/to/9.1/bin pg_ctl -D /path/to/copy/of/database -w start` PostgreSQL, then `pg_dump` it - if possible, using the *new* `pg_dump` from 9.3. I *strongly* recommend using `pg_dumpall --globals-only`, then a `pg_dump -Fc` for each individual database you wish to dump.

Now go check your backups and make sure that in future you're doing periodic dumps.